# Memcached always miss (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memcached

I have a class with this method:

```
def telecom_info

    Rails.cache.fetch("telecom_info_for_#{ref_num}", :expires_in=> 3.hours) do
      info = Hash.new(0)
      Telecom::SERVICES.each do |source|
          results = TelecomUsage.find(:all, 
                                      :joins=>[:telecom_invoice=>{ :person=> :org_person}], 
                                      :conditions=>"dotted_ids like '%#{ref_num}%' and telecom_usages.ruby_type = '#{source}'", 
                                      :select=>"avg(charge) #{source.upcase}_AVG_CHARGE,
                                                max(charge) #{source.upcase}_MAX_CHARGE,
                                                min(charge) #{source.upcase}_MIN_CHARGE,
                                                sum(charge) #{source.upcase}_CHARGE,
    
                                                avg(volume) #{source.upcase}_AVG_VOLUME,
                                                max(volume) #{source.upcase}_MAX_VOLUME,
                                                min(volume) #{source.upcase}_MIN_VOLUME,
                                                sum(volume) #{source.upcase}_VOLUME
                                                ")
    
          results = results.first
          ['charge', 'volume'].each do |source_type|                                        
            info["#{source}_#{source_type}".to_sym] = results.send("#{source}_#{source_type}".downcase).to_i
            info["#{source}_min_#{source_type}".to_sym] = results.send("#{source}_min_#{source_type}".downcase).to_i
            info["#{source}_max_#{source_type}".to_sym] = results.send("#{source}_max_#{source_type}".downcase).to_i
            info["#{source}_avg_#{source_type}".to_sym] = results.send("#{source}_avg_#{source_type}".downcase).to_i
          end
      end
      
      return info
    end
end
```

As you can see, this is an expensive call, and it is called ALOT for each request so I want to cache it. The problem is that memcached does not seem to work, in the log file, I am getting:

Cache read: telecom_info_for_60000000

Cache miss: telecom_info_for_60000000 ({})

The weird thing is that I know memcached is working since it does cache the results of some other functions I have in another model.

Any suggestions? I am running Rails 2.3.5 on REE 1.8.7

Comment: Didn't know there was a kind of flower called a stackover. Har har har.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace `return info` with `info`.

```
Rails.cache.fetch("telecom_info_for_#{ref_num}", :expires_in=> 3.hours) do
  # ...
  info
end
```

The `return` keyword always returns from the current **method**, which means that `info` is never returned to your call to `Rails.cache.fetch`, nor is the rest of that method ever executed. When the last statement simply is `info`, this is the value that will be given to `Rails.cache.fetch`, and you will allow the method to finish its duty by storing this value in the cache.

Compare the following:

```
def my_method
  1.upto(3) do |i|
    # Calling return immediately causes Ruby to exit the current method.
    return i
  end
end

my_method
#=> 1
```

As a rule of thumb: always omit `return` unless you really mean to exit the current block and return from the current method.